# How to combine SQL CASE statement with DISTINCT of another field

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, sum

I need to produce results for students.

I have a MySQL query giving the list of students and I am then using SELECT subqueries to give results from a few different tables based on different student activities.

For one subquery I need a points total which can be calculated using a CASE statement however this is calculated on all results and I need it to be based on the best result from each test as students often repeat a test to get a better result.

GROUP BY doesn't work on the SELECT subquery.

I thought DISTINCT would be my solution but I am not sure if its possible to perform DISTINCT on one field (TestID) while basing the CASE statement on a different field (percentage) although I presume it would need to be MAX(percentage) if thats then possible.

I seen similar examples doing this but they seem to involve using 'Then' to give the DISTINCT field and my example is using 'Then' to provide the points.

I have reduced the SQL down to the problem subquery below which produces a result but without making the 'testpoints' based on the best percentage of each TestID:

```
SELECT Students.UserID, Students.Name,  
(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Case When percentage >= '90' Then '2'
When percentage < '90' AND percentage > '0' Then '1'
Else '0'
END),0)
FROM TestResults
WHERE Students.UserID = TestResults.UserID) AS testpoints 
FROM Students
ORDER BY testpoints DESC
```

Students table is like this:

```
UserID   Name
1     David
2     Daisy
3     Sheila
```

TestResults is like this:

```
ID   UserID   TestID   percentage
1     1       1        100
2     1       2        100
3     2       1        100
4     2       1        80
5     2       2        100
6     3       2        100
```

The query above provides this result where it calculates multiple attempts of the same test:

```
UserID   Name     testpoints
1        David       4
2        Daisy       3  
3        Sheila      4
```

What I am trying to get is this with the duplicates removed and the points based on the maximum percentage for each test:

```
UserID   Name     testpoints
1        David       4
2        Daisy       2  
3        Sheila      2
```

If anyone can help on this I would be extremely grateful...

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

If I followed you correctly, you basically need two levels of aggregation for this: first get the best result per student and test, then sum them.

Here is one approach using a join on an aggregated query, then outer aggregation:

```
select
    s.userID,
    s.name,
    sum(t.testResults) testResults
from students s
inner join (
    select 
        userID, 
        testID, 
        case 
            when max(percentage) >= 90 then 2   
            when max(percentage) >=  0 then 1
            else 0 
        end testpoints
    from testResults
    group by userID, testID
) t on t.userID = s.userID
group by s.userID, s.name
```

Comment: Yes, I think you understand me correctly and it appears to be working correctly for the sample set of data I created. I am going to adapt it to the full database but so far so great!!!